# Convective/Material Derivative

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, fluid-dynamics

A concept in fluid dynamics requires the following derivative to be evaluated: $$ \frac{D\mathbf u}{Dt}  =
    \frac{\partial \mathbf u}{\partial t}+\mathbf v\cdot\nabla\mathbf u$$
This notation is very confusing to me - particulary the notion of gradient of the vector field $\mathbf u$. Is there any way to write this derivative in terms of $\mathbf {grad}, \mathbf {div}$ etc. in a way that allows its application in many different coordinate systems?

EDIT: this same derivative is also often written with additional parentheses (as below). Any clarification on this point?$$ \frac{D\mathbf u}{Dt}  =
    \frac{\partial \mathbf u}{\partial t}+\mathbf (v\cdot\nabla)\mathbf u$$

Comment: Does it help you writing out this material derivative? i.e 

$$\frac{D\mathbf u}{Dt}=\begin{pmatrix} \partial_t u_1 \\ \vdots \\ \partial_t u_n \end{pmatrix} + v_1\begin{pmatrix} \partial_1u_1 \\ \vdots \\ \partial_1u_n \end{pmatrix}+ ... +v_n \begin{pmatrix} \partial_nu_1 \\ \vdots \\ \partial_nu_n \end{pmatrix}$$